# can i make a temporary model from a findAll result?

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii

Can I make a temporary  model from a findAll result?

Similar to this command in sql:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```

I have a result model data in yii that I want get other result (like count or sum) after joining it to another result?

Comment: you can make a dynamic record for a table , but what do you mean result here ? what is your result ?

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi result=inion a query with dynamic record and get count and sum from relations this field. how can create dynamic record?

Comment: dynamic active record for a table $userModel = DynamicActiveRecord::forTable('user');

Comment: thanks i try it and say to aftr that